# Is there a way to have a member parameter type be a pointer to a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm writing a module system for my program, where individual modules are initialised and shutdown by a system.

how this works is I call an `Init()` function that will initialise a static pointer of the class.

this works and is fine, however: I would like to abstract this into a class so the api is easier to maintain, but I don't know how to change the pointer type of the derived class automatically

for example, if I have the base class `IModule`:

```cpp
class IModule {
public:
protected:
   result Init();
   result Shutdown();

private:
   static IModule* s_instance;
};
```

is there a way I can write this class so that the derived class can be written as

```cpp
class Derived : public IModule {
protected:
   result Init();
   result Shutdown();
}
```

and have `Derived::s_instance` evaluate to a `Derived*`

Comment: You can have virtual member functions but not virtual static data members or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't have a variable whose type depends on the type of `this`. *However*, you can have a variable whose type depends on a template parameter.

```
template <typename T>
class IModule {
private:
  static T* s_instance;
};

class Derived : public IModule<Derived> {
  // The s_instance in this class is of type Derived*.
}
```

This is called the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and it's used to do all sorts of tricks in C++. It may not work for your use case (for instance, you can no longer have a list of `IModule` which all have different derived types), but depending on what exactly you're doing this may be the way to go.

Comment: They can have the same base class if the class template derives from a non-template class interface.

Comment: Main idea in your answer is correct. However, you can actually have covariant return types in overrides - which is what OP is looking for I think. That said, you still can't have _any kind of_ return types, and CRTP is still valuable to mention, I'm just reasoning that maybe relax that 'no, you can't', to 'can only do if covariant'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as long as the return types are covariant, i.e., `Derived::Init()` returns something derived from `Derived::IModule()`'s return type. Which is I think the case here. A simplified version:

```
#include <iostream>

struct IModule {
   virtual IModule* Init() = 0;
   
private:
   static IModule* s_instance;
};

class Derived : public IModule {
    Derived* Init() override { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; return this; }
};

int main() {
    IModule* ptr = new Derived();
    ptr->Init(); // compile-time type: IModule, runtime: Derived
}
```

Comment: almost, I can probably make this work, the only thing being that Init doesn't return a pointer it returns an integer result. but would I be able to do this and instead of returning, i store a pointer of `Derived` and cast it to `IModule*` to store it in `s_instance`?